# Jasperreport mongodb count result

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

How can I count the number of result in JasperReports use with mongodb?

In mongo to get count I can use :

```
db.book.count({'genre.name':'action'})
```

In JasperReports (6.6.0) I try :

```
{ collectionName : 'book', count : { genre.name : 'action' }}
```

and

```
{ collectionName : 'book', count : { findQuery : { genre.name : 'action'} }}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use variable (built-in variables) for getting total number of rows or number rows at group

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try $V{REPORT_COUNT} in summary band and it's work!

Answer (score 1):

More general answer would be something like this:

```
{
    runCommand: {
        aggregate: "book",
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    genre: {$exists: true},
                    "genre.name": {$eq: "action"}
                }
            }, 
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null, count: {$sum: 1}
                }
            }           
        ]
    }
}
```

It's the chain of commands, which are executed in order of appearance:

- match fetches from your collection documents, which fulfill the criteria
- group returns a document, which contains result of group operations, like sum, min, max, average